# Mantaflow error when filling a collision object mesh

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

First time I encountered a problem like this one, when there is an invisible obstacle inside my mesh, that is set as a collision effector with the liquid simulation.

I have checked, there is no hidden mesh problems or inaccuracies, so have no idea why it does this with the flow.

[image]

Comment: Pls provide blend file

Comment: @Chris hi, im not sure how to- add it as a zip to my initial post?